# Grouping with Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset I am trying to group by some common values and then sum up some other values. The tricky part is I want to add some sort of weighting that keeps the largest number, I'll try to elaborate more below:

I've created a dummy data frame that is along the lines of my data just for example purposes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Family': ['Contactors', 'Contactors', 'Contactors'], 
                   'Cell': ['EP&C', 'EXR', 'C&S'],
                    'Visits': ['25620', '626', '40']})
```

This produces a table like so:

[image]

So, in this example I would want all of the 'Contactors' to be grouped up by EP&C (as this has the highest visits to start with) but I would like all of the visits summed up and the other 'Cell' values dropped, so I would be left with something like this:

[image]

Could anyone advise?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use:

```
(df
 # convert to numeric
 .assign(Visits=pd.to_numeric(df['Visits']))
 # ensure the top row per group is the highest visits
 .sort_values(by=['Family', 'Visits'], ascending=False)
 # for groups per Family
 .groupby('Family', sort=False, as_index=False)
 # aggregate per group: Cell (first row, i.e top) and Visits (sum of rows)
 .agg({'Cell': 'first', 'Visits': sum})
)
```

output:

```
       Family  Cell  Visits
0  Contactors  EP&C   26286
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! If you wouldn't mind, could you explain your code a bit more? I'm unfamiliar with .agg for example.

Comment: Hi @mozway, may I ask: is it possible to use inplace=true here to store the new dataframe? I am having trouble with this.

Comment: @Stuquan given the different shape, not directly, what would be the expected output?

Comment: I'd want to export this output into a .csv file.

Comment: I meant the explicit data, not the storage ;)

Comment: sorry I'm not 100% sure what you mean, I'm still sorta new to this :D I would want the df you assisted with above to replace the one I source from my current excel file so that I can export it back out to csv... right now if I try to call df.head() it reverts back to my original dataframe because I can't add inplace=true.. sorry if that is confusing!

Comment: I don't fully understand what you want (perhaps this should be a new question), but I am fairly sure `inplace=True` is not what you're looking for ;)